# Capture and study the graphs/charts using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to analyze the graphs on a web page with the help of Selenium webdriver. Here analysis means that we need to check whether the graph created by data is correct when compared with actual data available in the database. PFB the flow:
i. User clicks on a link, which then opens a page having some graphs (pie as well as bar charts).
ii. At the backend, the required data is fetched from the Database and passed in response to the application.
iii. This data is then passed on to a third party tool, protovis, which then converts the data into required graph and displays the graphs on screen.

Need to know whether it is at all feasible all or not to do this with Selenium webdriver (2.0). If no, then is there any other way by which this can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could configure the driver to download the generated image and compare it with the data you have, but you will need some tool that could compare the image and the data.